# Accepted AppStore app crash on every device

Tags: ios, crash, app-store, crash-reports

Just released this morning an app that I tested on all possible devices and simulators, but when I downloaded it from the store the application crashes at startup. I have tested it on many devices and iOS versions, but the result is the same:

```
Incident Identifier: B34024C9-9F00-4E57-B3AB-068CFFC55119
CrashReporter Key:   81ac2324b459bfeeb1a13c007d9d04e59e6efaf2
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         iMatematica [9546]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CFFA51F9-52F9-4555-8C5B-1B2DDF5E2D5B/iMatematica.app/iMatematica
Identifier:      iMatematica
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-08-04 07:24:08.703 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35eb532c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a01208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329fa298 abort + 88
3   iMatematica                     0x0007eee0 0x1000 + 515808
4   CoreFoundation                  0x355ff950 __handleUncaughtException + 68
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x379a633e _objc_terminate + 122
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x359b53be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x359b544a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x359b681e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x379a62a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35555506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35555366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  UIKit                           0x33064864 -[UIApplication _run] + 544
13  UIKit                           0x33061cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  iMatematica                     0x00009a88 main (main.m:18)
15  iMatematica                     0x000039b0 0x1000 + 10672

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ea53a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3448ff04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3448fc22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35eb5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329bcf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329bccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35eb5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329bcf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329bccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ea5004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ea51fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x355d33ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x355d2124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3555549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35555366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x31454c9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329c272e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329c25e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ea5004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ea51fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x355d33ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x355d2124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3555549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35555366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x3508ebb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x3508ea7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x3512258a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329c272e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x329c25e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35eb5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329bcf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x329bccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ec0cd98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdff9c0
    r8: 0x3f02bce0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x0021f0a0     r11: 0x33410c0d
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdff9b4      lr: 0x32a0120f      pc: 0x35eb532c
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

The problem is only happening to me or is the same as last month: that is a problem of apple server that sign apps?

Comment: There is an exception happening, see line 9 and 4. To see the original point in the source where this occurs you would need the "Last Exception Backtrace" to be present it the crash report which sadly isn't. One suggestion: re-sign your app store build with your developer certificate and try to reproduce the crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem: changing the language from Italian (my native language) to English, the application works properly. This explains why the AppReview Team has not noticed the crash, and was due to a missing localization in a xib file: "Could not load NIB bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'MasterViewController'"

Comment: Ah, but he hasn't accepted his post as the answer yet - +1 from me when he does :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will be able to do it in 2 days :)